# Is it advisable to include credit card statements for my UK visitor visa?

Tags: visas, payment-cards

I use my credit card for almost all transactions and I pay my credit card bill regularly.

Can I submit my credit card statements and available credit limit as a proof of subsistence for UK visitor visa application?

Will they take it as a negative, if I rely on my credit card statement?

Answer (score 5):

**No**, it is not advisable.

> **Section 4: documents you should not send unless specifically requested**
>
> This page provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to consider your application.
>
> ...
>
> credit card statements
>
> ...

Source: [UKVI Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf)